# How do I type hint a filename in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

What is a best way in Python to hint a filename,
so that it's acceptable to pass anything into a function that you can open as a file?

Especially both strings and files found via Pathlib.

```
def myfunc(filename: str) -> None:
    with open(filename) as f1:
        # do something here
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is Structural Typing, which is not yet supported. It is proposed in [PEP 544](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/).

In the mean time, you could do a half-way effort by annotating with `Union[str, bytes, os.PathLike]`.

Comment: @576i PEP 544 is supported in the recently-released Python 3.8.

Comment: given the support of PEP 544 in Python 3.8,  what is the proper hint to use for a file name?

Comment: I've just looked through PEP544 again and had a wee look at the libraries supplied with Python3.8, and I can't see anything immediately useful. So while Structural Typing would appear to be the way that it *ought* to be done, there doesn't appear to be anything official that makes use of it just yet.

Comment: `open()` also allows file descriptor numbers (of type `int`) as its first argument. It's debatable whether it's a good idea to declare that in the interface given the large ambiguity.

Answer (score 28):

[PEP 519](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0519/#provide-specific-type-hinting-support) recommends using `typing.Union[str, bytes, os.PathLike]`

Comment: I added this as a separate answer because lxop's answer primarily recommends using Structural Typing.

Comment: I use this: `PathLike = TypeVar("PathLike", str, pathlib.Path, None)`

Answer (score 15):

As Eric said,

> [PEP 519](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0519/#provide-specific-type-hinting-support) recommends using `typing.Union[str, bytes, os.PathLike]`.

and this is the easiest option.

But you should consider also `_typeshed.AnyPath`: it supports all kinds of paths in accordance with the different versions, and it is the default typing hint in the built-in library for filenames, such as in [the function `open()` itself](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/5f9fd3d1272728a07ba7cd6cfe298151fd10d8b9/stdlib/2and3/builtins.pyi#L1471-L1477).
Importing it results in your type helper recognising that the input should be a filename, and may help type hinting paths. It has also the variations `_typeshed.StrPath` for strings only and `_typeshed.BytesPath` for bytestrings only. [Here for their definition](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/0b1cd5989669544866213807afa833a88f649ee7/stdlib/_typeshed/__init__.pyi#L56-L65).

However, you can't just import the `typeshed` module, as [it doesn't exist at runtime](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/0b1cd5989669544866213807afa833a88f649ee7/stdlib/_typeshed/__init__.pyi#L3-L13). The easiest solution to this is to import it only during type-checking (because it's the only time you need it):

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
AnyPath = None
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from _typeshed import AnyPath
```

Lastly, in the current 3.10 beta build, `AnyPath` [has been renamed to](https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/5470) `StrOrBytesPath`, in order to separate the strings and the bytestrings from the paths of the Path module, and another AnyPath wont be seen soon. So, if you are planning to input only str filenames, you can use `_typeshed.StrPath`, or just give up and use `typing.Union[str, bytes, os.PathLike]`.

Answer (score 5):

As of PEP 604 (https://peps.python.org/pep-0604/) and python 3.10, the | operator can now be used for unions of type hints.

So the OPs example could now look like:

```
def myfunc(filename: str | os.PathLike) -> None:
    with open(filename) as f1:
```

Answer (score 1):

What I normally do in big projects is defining a [`TypeAlisas`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases):

```
from typing import TypeAlias

FileName: TypeAlias = str | bytes | os.PathLike
```

Thus, this alias can be used directly, resulting in a cleaner syntax:

```
def myfunc(filename: FileName) -> None:
    with open(filename) as f1:
        # do something here
```