# How do I use Structural Typing to hint a filename?

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

In [How do I type hint a filename in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53418046/how-do-i-type-hint-a-filename-in-a-function), it was asked

> What is a best way in Python to hint a filename, so that it's acceptable to pass anything into a function that you can open as a file?

at the time, @lxop [wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53418245/2088857)

> I think what you are looking for is Structural Typing, which is not yet supported. It is proposed in PEP 544.

Given that [Python 3.8+ has Structural Typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53418046/how-do-i-type-hint-a-filename-in-a-function#comment108028999_53418245), how should we use Structural Typing hints for filenames?

Comment: N.B. @lxop mentioned (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53418046/how-do-i-type-hint-a-filename-in-a-function#comment117224780_53418245) that they had not yet found an "official" use of Structural Typing for filenames, but this might have changed in the last ~18 months. It may be that this question does not yet have an answer.

Comment: If you scroll down a bit in the thread @kc9jud linked, there is a excerpt from PEP 519: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61804884/14536215

Comment: @Tzane ah, I guess I misunderstood that -- the recommendation from PEP 519 still stands even with PEP 544?

Comment: I would assume so. At least PEP 519 isn't mentioned in 544, but I admit I haven't read the whole thing, so I could be proven wrong